# Seceding tasks from thread pools in dask distributed

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I've been going through the documentation on spawning new processes from a task running on a worker. I came across this from [here](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html):

> However, each running task takes up a single thread, and so if you launch many tasks that launch other tasks then it is possible to deadlock the system if you are not careful. You can call the secede function from within a task to have it remove itself from the dedicated thread pool into an administrative thread that does not take up a slot within the Dask worker

What does it mean to move to an administrative thread? Are all slots given the same priority or something similar? And the administrative thread does have priority?

As a concrete example, here is what I'm thinking of trying:

```
from dask.distributed import get_client, secede

def compute_square(x):
    # Get locally created client
    client = get_client()
    secede()  # or not?
    if x > 5:
        client.submit(lambda x : x**2, x)
```

where `compute_square` and the `lambda` function could potentially be run quite a few times, and would be a more computationally intensive function worth the 1ms overhead of submitting jobs.
Should I be using `secede` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean to move to an administrative thread?

Dask workers maintain a fixed-sized thread pool for running tasks.  When you call `secede` your computation leaves this thread pool and opens up another slot for other tasks to run instead.  Your task's thread still exists, but is just a normal thread.  The term "administrative thread" doesn't mean anything in particular other than "a thread not in the thread pool".

> Are all slots given the same priority or something similar?

Once tasks are running there is no priority between them.  They all run in normal Python threads for which there is no prioritization.

> And the administrative thread does have priority?

No

> Should I be using secede in this case?

You should call `secede` if

1. There is a possibility that you will call enough tasks that are all waiting on other tasks so that no tasks can finish because all of your thread-pool's threads are waiting for other slots to open up.
2. You do not intend to do much more work in that task

You should not call `secede` if

1. You intend to do much more computationally bound work in the task after you call `secede`.  This would still be OK, but is somewhat impolite because Dask will feel comfortable launching several of these tasks without any sort of limitations.